# Funcion SQL sobre estado de un servicio

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
     CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Estado (@SRV_ID INTEGER) RETURNS CHAR(1) AS

   BEGIN
   DECLARE @E_ESTADO CHAR(1);
                            WHEN 'P' THEN 'En proceso'
                            WHEN 'C' THEN 'Creado'
                            WHEN 'F' THEN 'Finalizado'
                            ELSE 'No Indicado'
     FROM SERVICIOS
     WHERE SRV_ID = @SRV_ID
     RETURN @E_ESTADO
     END
     GO
```

Necesitaría que la función me retorne el estado del servicio, pero no como "A" y la "I" sino como Activo o Inactivo

Comment: Hola. No sé entiende cuál es tu problema. Por favor ve a [edit] y amplía la descripción

Comment: A esa función le faltan lineas de código. Pero creo que el problema está en la definición del tipo de dato que regresa y la variable que usas.

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola! con esto lo deberías poder resolver, debes reemplazar CampoDeLaTablaQueGuardaEstado por el campo que tienes en la tabla SERVICIOS que guarda el estado ("P","C","F", etc):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Estado (@SRV_ID INTEGER) 
RETURNS CHAR(15) AS
   BEGIN
   DECLARE @E_ESTADO CHAR(15);
   SELECT @E_ESTADO = 
   CASE CampoDeLaTablaQueGuardaEstado
        WHEN 'P' THEN 'En proceso'
        WHEN 'C' THEN 'Creado'
        WHEN 'F' THEN 'Finalizado'
        ELSE 'No Indicado'
   FROM SERVICIOS
   WHERE SRV_ID = @SRV_ID
   RETURN @E_ESTADO
   END
   GO
```